# Implementing an offline queue backed with a persistent store using Mailcore2 and MCOOperationQueue

Tags: ios, queue, imap, offline, mailcore2

I wanted to implement an offline queue backed by a persistent store using mailcore2. E.g., if you archive when there's no Internet, it should retry again when reachability changes.

With the way MCOOperationQueue is set up, would it just be best to subclass NSOperation and wrap the MCOOperations inside the calls with reachability or is there a better strategy?

I found an issue referencing this topic stating that my above suggested implementation "won't behave properly". [#458](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/issues/458)

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: I think a better strategy would be to keep a list of changes and remove items from that list when the change has been applied.